「お前」にも「さん」をつけること
「お前」という二人称は歴史的に不尊敬の意味がなく、実は敬語として用いられていたことは知っていますが、現代にはまだそういう用例があるのですか？ 特に、ゲームをやっていた時、こういう会話を見てちょっと不思議だと思いました。


ここでは「お前さん」と「お前さんら」の用例が見つかります。このゲームの世界観は江戸時代の日本に基づいており、会話や文法は大体現代語です。なので、これはとある現代方言の喋り方かもしれないと思いました。本当にそうですか？ 現代標準語しか喋らない日本人は「お前さん」と呼ばれるとどう受け取りますか？（特に相手が東京一帯からの人ではなく方言を喋っているらしい場合？）

精選版日本国語大辞典に、この語についての歴史が載っています。

お前さん
(「おまえさま」の変化した語 ) 対称。江戸時代には、一般社会でも遊里でも使用され、かなり高い敬意を表わした。庶民階級で、妻がその夫を呼ぶ時にも用いる。おまいさん。
[初出の実例]「なるほどおまへさんのおっしゃるが御尤でござります」(出典：洒落本・青楼五雁金（1788）三)
御前様の語誌
( 1 )近世前期上方で生まれ、最高の待遇価値をもった「おまえさま」の親愛的な表現として一般に普及した。
( 2 )近世後期に「あなた」が生まれて敬意を下げたが、上方では「おまいさん」、遊里から生じて広まった「おまえはん」「おまはん」など多様な形があり、江戸では庶民に「おめへさん」の形で多用された。

「お前さん」は、江戸時代には主に目上の人に対して使われており、現代でいう「お客様」などと同程度の、強い敬意を持っていたようです。
敬意逓減の法則 (pejoration) に基づき、昭和の時代には「お前さん」が持つ敬意はかなり低下していました。妻が夫に呼びかけたり、対等な同僚や友人に呼びかけたりする際のフレーズとして広く認識されていました。
現代では「お前さん」の使用自体がかなり稀になっており、現実世界では廃れつつある呼称です。今では落語、演歌の歌詞、昔話などで聞くことがある語として主に認識されています。
ただし現代のフィクションでは、様々な世界観の作品で、古風な呼称として比較的広く使われています。例えば、老婆の魔女、老賢者、高飛車な王族、気難しいドワーフの鍛冶屋、といったステレオタイプを持つキャラクターは、今でも「お前さん」をしばしば使っています。こういう場合の「お前さん」に「お前」のような失礼さはありませんが、明確な敬意もありません。

わかりました、やはり現実生活で使うのはダメですよね（笑

詳しくて素敵な回答でありがとうございます
